# Global title variables

Tags: asp-classic

Due to a lack of choice I am architecting a aspx site where I do not have access to the global.asa file or a database. One of the requirements is the ability to easily change page titles, breadcrumbs and breadcrumb URL's. I am thinking of including a titles.apsx page at the top of all my pages and then storing the variables in it with unique variable id's for each then using response.write at the page level to display them on the page.

Is this a god idea? Anyone have a better idea?

Thanks in advance

Thanks for the answer but I do not think it is quite what I am loking for. I am wanting to set title variables for numerous pages in one centralized document. My site is approximatly 3000 pages and I anticipate changing breadcrumb and title names numerous times throughout the development period.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you want to do there.

The easiest way to change a `<title>` in aspx, is to treat it like any other element:

```
<html><head>
<title id="pagetitle" runat="server"></title>
```

and in your code:

```
pagetitle.InnerHtml = "Title for this page";
```